# How can I disable some routing components to display?

Tags: reactjs

I am making a web site which classified users into the admin and normal ones.

Some routing components should not be displayed like the view of other users' detail unless he is a authenticated user.

Besides, not only it should be displayed to the normal user, it also could not be accessible by the normal user. Where should I modify the code **ReactDOM.render(.....)** or inside the component ?

Answer (score 0):

You should do it inside the component. `ReactDOM.render` takes in a React component and a DOM element. It is used to let React take control of the contents of that DOM element by rendering that component within it. Typically, most web apps only have one `ReactDOM.render` and it is used at the root of the HTML `<body>`.

What you want to achieve is called conditional rendering. In the example below, The "Edit profile" button will be rendered if `this.state.profileBelongsToUser` is `true`. Else it is not rendered in the DOM. You will have to fetch some data to decide the value of that boolean flag.

```
class Profile extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // Initialize / set state probably by fetching some data.
    this.state = {
      profileBelongsToUser: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1>Profile page</h1>
          <p>Name: John Doe</p>
          {this.state.profileBelongsToUser ? <button>Edit profile</button> : null}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```